# Where can I get a replacement case for my Nikon SB400 flash?

Tags: flash

I've lost the case for my SB400 Nikon flash and am having a devile of a time finding a replacement. I've Googled and so far, no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. A quick search tells me the case is the SS400, but I don't see it for sale anywhere. That said, I'd expect any small soft bag to be an adequate replacement.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Nikon? You might be able to get it from them directly as a replacement part.

Comment: Damn, I have that exact flash and I don't use it anymore.  Dunno where the case is, but I probably use it for storing USB keys or something.  That said, for cases for these types of things the [free sunglasses cases you get when you buy sunglasses at chemists (the ones with the drawstrings)](http://www.rapideyewear.co.uk/shopimages/products/normal/Pouch.jpg) work well for me.  Maybe you can pick up a pair of sunnies as a bonus.

Comment: There are companies available in the market, where you can search your case. But, before roaming here and there, you can check this [link](http://www.hotfrog.com/Products/Camera-Parts) for your better convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried so hard to find it, but was unsuccessful.

Go on http://www.nikon.com/index.htm and chose your location
and select 'whereToBuy' section. This will give you a lot of authorized stores.

You can also check here: http://www.nikonusa.com/en/index.page

I found lots of soft cases, but not the SB-400. Write them an email and maybe they can get one for you